# Why is strtotime() giving the wrong date?

Tags: php, strtotime

I'm using the following code

```
$t = strtotime('Saturday, 28 Dec, 2013');
echo date('d/m/Y H:i',$t);
// output : 03/01/2015 20:13

$t = strtotime('Wednesday, 01 Jan, 2014');
echo date('d/m/Y H:i',$t);
// output: 01/01/2014 20:14
```

The first example prints out the wrong date, and the second one prints out the correct date.

Why is this and how do I fix it?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: @putvande Self-explanatory. Why is "Saturday, 28 Dec, 2013" being parsed to output "January 3rd, 2015"?

Comment: Use `$t = strtotime('Saturday, 28 Dec 2013');`

Comment: @user2727841 I believe he did.

Comment: The question is straightforward, please don't make confusion when there is no point in doing it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`strtotime` only understands a [specific set of formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php). If your input is not in one of these formats, it will do its best to guess, but as you can see the results can vary.

Try this:

```
$t = date_create_from_format("D, d M, Y","Saturday, 28 Dec, 2013");
echo date_format($t,"d/m/Y H:i");
```

Answer (score 7):

You have an unnecessary comma, after the month. Remove that, and your code will work as intended:

```
$t = strtotime('Saturday, 28 Dec 2013');
echo date('d/m/Y H:i',$t);

$t = strtotime('Wednesday, 01 Jan 2014');
echo date('d/m/Y H:i',$t);
```

But I would suggest you, to use [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) class for this instead. That way, you can use any date format you want:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('l, d M, Y', 'Saturday, 28 Dec, 2013');
echo $date->format('d/m/Y H:i');

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('l, d M, Y', 'Wednesday, 01 Jan, 2014');
echo $date->format('d/m/Y H:i');
```